# wxpython How to set dialog size fit to data in the dialog?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a dialog window in `wxpython` as follows:

```
wx.Dialog.__init__(self,parent, title=_("Sum Report"),size=(840,680))
```

This give me the dialog with the selected size... However The dialog has different information for different users.. This caused that some of the users get horizontal scroll bar:

[image]

Is there a way to create the dialog so that the horizontal size will be dynamic (fit to the data)? The vertical size is always OK no need to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use any fix sizes, use sizers and then call .Fit() on the Dialog, Panel or Frame.

Answer (score 1):

Calling .Fit() won't work. I tested it.

Although window size fit to content, it goes blank.

You must use **self.SetSizerAndFit(box_sizer)**